# Xamarin MasterDetail page black screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am implementing an APP with Xamarin using MasterDetail page

However in iOS encountered a black screen issue.

Here is example.

If I don't put a detail page in Xaml file like below.

```
<MasterDetailPage>
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title = "Menu">
            <ScrollView>
            ...
            </ScrollView>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>

    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:xxx_Page />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

During runtime. If I called below

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
```

In iOS system. The phone enters a black screen

In Android. It works fine.

Is there any reason?

Answer (score 0):

MasterDetailPage is obsolete. You can use FlyoutPage instead.
I used FlyoutPage to refer to your code and simply tested it on iOS without any problems, hope it can help you:

For .xaml file:

```
<FlyoutPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlyoutPageNavigation;assembly=FlyoutPageNavigation"
        x:Class="FlyoutPageNavigation.MainPage">
<FlyoutPage.Flyout>
    <ContentPage Title="Menu">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="One"/>
                <Label Text="Two"/>
                <Label Text="Three"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage>
</FlyoutPage.Flyout>
```

For .cs file:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace FlyoutPageNavigation
{
    public partial class MainPage : FlyoutPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Detail=new NavigationPage(new ContactsPage());
        }  
    }
}
```

For more usage of Flyout, you can refer to the documentation: [Xamarin.Forms FlyoutPage | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/flyoutpage)